# how to click the video automatically by mouse every 10 sec, Python

Tags: python, image-processing, mouseevent, hsv, color-detection

My algorithm is suffering from illumination change which depends on the color tracking in an indoor environment. So, I'd like to update the lower and upper values of HSV every 10 seconds using clicking by mouse automatically. I'm using Python, OpenCV for color tracking by the robot.

The desired region for clicking on it for example (320, 240) pixel.

The full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time


class ColorTracker(object):
    # path = "../videos/ball.mp4"
    path = 0  # set the path of video to load and for primary camera keep it 0, for second camera 1 and so on.
    hue_tolerance = 10

    mouse_clicked = False
    frame = np.zeros((480, 640, 3), np.uint8)
    b, g, r = 0, 0, 0
    cx, cy = 0, 0
    cap = None
    color_lower_range = (0, 0, 0)
    color_higher_range = (0, 0, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.path)
        cv2.namedWindow("Color Tracker")
        cv2.setMouseCallback('Color Tracker', self.getCoords)

    def getCoords(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.cx, self.cy = x, y

            self.b, self.g, self.r = self.frame[self.cy, self.cx]
            self.b, self.g, self.r = int(self.b), int(self.g), int(self.r)

            frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            h, s, v = frame_hsv[self.cy, self.cx]
            h, s, v = int(h), int(s), int(v)
            print(h, s, v)

            h_low = h - self.hue_tolerance
            h_high = h + self.hue_tolerance
            if h_low < 0:
                h_low = 0
            if h_high > 179:
                h_high = 179

            s_low = s - 10
            s_high = s + 10
            if s_low < 0:
                s_low = 0
            if s_high > 255:
                s_high = 255

            v_low = v - 15
            v_high = v + 15
            if v_low < 0:
                v_low = 0
            if v_high > 255:
                v_high = 255

            self.color_lower_range = (h_low, 100, 100)
            self.color_higher_range = (h_high, 255, 255)

            if s < 100:
                self.color_lower_range = (h_low, s_low, 100)
                self.color_higher_range = (h_high, s_high, 255)
            if v < 100:
                self.color_lower_range = (h_low, 100, v_low)
                self.color_higher_range = (h_high, 255, v_high)
            if s < 100 and v < 100:
                self.color_lower_range = (h_low, s_low, v_low)
                self.color_higher_range = (h_high, s_high, v_high)

            self.mouse_clicked = True

    def start(self):
        while (True):
            available, self.frame = self.cap.read()

            # frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
            if not self.mouse_clicked:
                cv2.imshow("Color Tracker", self.frame)
            else:
                frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                # cv2.imshow("frame_hsv",frame_hsv)
                mask = cv2.inRange(frame_hsv, self.color_lower_range, self.color_higher_range)
                # cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
                mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
                blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
                img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
                cv2.drawContours(self.frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
                cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (5, 5), (20, 20), (self.b, self.g, self.r), -1)
                cv2.imshow("Color Tracker", self.frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(100) == 13:
                break

    def end(self):
        self.cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


CT = ColorTracker()
CT.start()
CT.end()
```

pleas help or any suggestions

Comment: why do you need mouse for this? Can't you run it directly ?

Comment: How? my purpose is to update the values every 10 seconds using the mouse or something else.

Comment: then check `time.time()` in every loop and run code which you have in `getCoords`

Comment: if you really need to control mouse then see modules [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html) or [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, @furas. I will try to use both.

Comment: What about using pyauto gui? https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/